# Reading from an array before appending items to it (crash)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

Under the class initialization I set:

```
var cardsCover = [PFFile]()
```

I have two functions. One of them take from Parse.com data and append it to arrays:

```
     let cards = PFQuery(className: "cards")
        cards.whereKey("category", equalTo: "Fruits")

        cards.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (cards: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in                
            if error == nil {
                for card in cards! {
                    self.cardsCover.append(card["cover"] as! PFFile)
                }
            } else {
                print("error")
            }
         }
```

and the second function takes from this `cardsCover` array and show the items:

```
self.cardsCover[self.cardIndex].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if imageData != nil {
             let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
             let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
             contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        } else {
              print(error)
        }
 }
```

but when I launch my app it at first try to show images from an empty array, instead of appending items to array and just later to read from it. So, it crashes.

I set breakpoint to the first line of my second func and when I type:

```
po cardsCover
```

it returns `0 elements`.

How can I solve this problem and make at first, append items to my array and just later to read them from it?

Comment: When do you call exactly your second piece of code?

Comment: both functions are inside of `viewDidLoad` @Larme

Comment: My question, is when do you do `self.cardsCover[self.cardIndex].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock etc`. For example, you may want to call this code after the for loop: `for card in cards!{}`.

Comment: @Larme I did not understand you =/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, while fetching elements from an Array, always put a safe check on array size to avoid the crash.

Second, you need to ensure that function to read data from `cardsCover` gets always called after data setter function is called. You have a completion block in data fetcher where in you can trigger the data fetcher. You can also implement `delegate` callbacks or post a notification once data download is done so data usage could start thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

I think getDataInBackgroundWithBlock is asynchronous API (sounds like its running off the main queue) so you need to dispatch to the main queue. Here is how to do it

```
if self.cardsCover.count > self.cardIndex {
    self.cardsCover[self.cardIndex].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in  
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {              
            if imageData != nil {
                if let image = UIImage(data: imageData!){
                    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
                    contentView.addSubview(imageView)
                } else { print ("imageData can not be converted to image") }
            } else {
                print("There was no imageData")
            }
        }
    }
} else { print("cardIndex bigger than array count") }
```

Comment: nothing. It prints again `fatal error: Array index out of range`

Comment: could it be that, you're fetching the data in another thread so you might wanna get the main thread when its done

Comment: I did a similar project long ago, let me check and will edit my answer

Comment: I've changed it, but nothing again. It crashes, anyway

Comment: maybe the imageData is not retuning an image, check it with if let

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92476/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-lukas).